# How can I configure applications only for mix-test?

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

Suppose we have a module `A` that requires a configuration. When we consume A, it's just OK to put `[applications: [:a]]` in mix.exs and put `config :a, []` in config/config.exs in our project.

But when we're developers of the module A, how/when can we configure `:a` on a command of `mix test` in the A directory? Can we do that in test/test_helpers.exs or somewhere?

Comment: Is putting config inside `if Mix.env == :test do ... end` in config.exs not what you want?

Comment: @Dogbert Thank you, that's what I want. `mix test` changes `Mix.env` to be `:test`, I see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to derive the behaviour from [`Phoenix`](http://www.phoenixframework.org/). What it does, is basically three additional files in `config` directory, named `dev.exs`, `prod.exs` and `test.exs` and the following clause in `config.exs`:

```
import_config "#{Mix.env}.exs"
```

Since `mix` sets the `Mix.env` appropriately, the respective configuration will be loaded.